# Check if file exists in S3 Bucket

Tags: bash, files, aws, amazon-s3, amazon

This directory `/data/files/` has thousands files like:

```
1test
2test
3test

[...]

60000test
60001test
```

I'm also sending them to a S3 Bucket (AWS), using `AWS CLI`. However, sometimes the S3 bucket can be offline and because of that the file is skipped.

How can I check if the file that exists in `/data/files/` is also in the S3 Bucket? and if not copy the missing file to S3?

I would prefer to do this using BASH. Also if I need to change the AWS CLI for another one, can be.

Comment: There are a bunch of command-line tools that talk to S3 such as `s3cmd` and `s4cmd` and FUSE filesystems such as s3fs and s3ql. There are also things like `rclone` which probably solve your entire problem for you. What are you currently using to talk to S3?

Comment: @derobert i'm using the `aws cli` - If you have an example to help please feel free to answer the question.

Comment: I'd think `rclone copy /data/files whatever:` would do everything for you... But anyway, you should [edit] your question to clarify which software you're using to talk to AWS. And if you're open to switching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using `rclone`[1] as @derobert has suggested.

The command is very simple:

```
rclone check sourcepath remote:s3bucketname
```

Example:

Let's imagine you want to check if the S3 bucket (bucket name: `tmp_data_test_bucket`) has all the files that this directory has: `/tmp/data/`

Command:

```
rclone check /tmp/data/ remote:tmp_data_test_bucket
```

[1] http://rclone.org/

Comment: rclone is not a native call, I don't consider this the best solution.

Answer (score 16):

If you do `aws s3 ls` on the actual filename. If the filename exists, the exit code will be 0 and the filename will be displayed, otherwise, the exit code will not be 0:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/filname
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `s3 ls` will list the file and give a return code of 0 (success) even if you provide a partial path.  For example, `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/filen` will list the file `s3://bucket/filename`.

Answer (score 3):

first answer is close but in cases where you use -e in shebang, the script will fail which you would most like not want. It is better to use wordcount. So you can use the below command:

```
wordcount=`aws s3 ls s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/${folder}/|grep $${file}|wc -c`
echo wordcount=${wordcount}
if [[ "${wordcount}" -eq 0 ]]; then
do something
else
do something
fi
```

Comment: `$${file}` will expand to the PID and `{file}`, probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following :

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket ${S3_BUCKET} --key ${S3_KEY}
```

It retrieves the **metadata** of the object without retrieving the object itself. **READ(s3:GetObject)** access is required. 
.

Comment: This is great, especially since it returns a JSON if you want to find a specific field, it's easy to grab the value.

Answer (score 0):

I created two functions as an example because I figured I might want to know the size of the file and I may want to know if the file exists.

This function  gets the size of the file and "returns" it as an echo:

```
s3_file_size() {
    if command -v aws &> /dev/null; then
        echo "$(aws s3 ls "${1}" --summarize | grep "Total.*Size" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')"
        return 0
    else
        echo "Warn-${FUNCNAME[0]}, AWS command missing."
        return 1
    fi
}
```

This function uses the other one to determine if it receives a file size of 0 which will imply the file is essentially not there. (yes it will treat a file of size 0 as not there)

```
s3_does_file_exist() {
    if command -v aws &> /dev/null; then
        [[ $(s3_file_size "${1}") -lt 1 ]] && return 1 || return 0
    else
        echo "Warn-${FUNCNAME[0]}, AWS command missing."
        return 1
    fi
}
```